# XmlSerializer is not serializing to a valid xml

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

Please Consider the following code:

```
public class Obj : IObj
{
    public string Prop1{get;set;}
    public string Prop2{get;set;}
    public string Prop3{get;set;}
}

public static void Persist(IObj obj, string fileFullName)
{
    try
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileFullName));

        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

        using (var fileStream = File.Open(fileFullName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(fileStream, obj);
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       //log
    }
}
```

When calling '*Persist*' on '*Obj*' for the first time, I get a valid xml file on disk, which looks something like this:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <Obj xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
>     <Prop1>value1</Prop1>
>     <Prop2>value2</Prop2>
>     <Prop2>value3</Prop3>
> </Obj>
> ```

But when '*Persist*' is called for the second time on '*Obj*' (after changing '*value1*' to '*value*', for example), an extra *'>'* sign is added at the end of the file, making it non-valid.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <Obj xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
>     <Prop1>value</Prop1>
>     <Prop2>value2</Prop2>
>     <Prop2>value3</Prop3>
> </Obj>>
> ```

I tried to debug it but didn't find any abnormalities, so I'm guessing it has to do
with the way that I'm opening the file.
Any help explaining it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the file exists, you are opening it and overwriting as many bytes as needed. If that's fewer than the current file length, you'll have left over characters at the end. Try using `FileMode.Create` instead.

Comment: beat me to it ;p and entirely correct. To quote MSDN (for `Create`): "Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. If the file already exists, it will be overwritten. This requires FileIOPermissionAccess.Write. System.IO.FileMode.Create is equivalent to requesting that if the file does not exist, use CreateNew; otherwise, use Truncate. "

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you'll only see this when the subsequent XML is smaller than the previous - You need to set the length of the `fileStream` with something like:

```
xmlSerializer.Serialize(fileStream, obj);
if (fileStream.CanSeek)
{
     fileStream.SetLength(fileStream.Position);
}
```

Alternately, specify `FileMode.Create` when creating the stream

Comment: This would also fix it, yes; opening with `Create` would be preferred, but this is a good answer for when your code gets *handed* a `FileStream` and wasn't responsible for creating/opening the file

Comment: As a stylistic note, I'd tend to favour a `Persist` method that took a stream, with an overload that takes a file - handy for later on if you wanted to persist to a `MemoryStream` in a unit test, for example... (that's also why I check `CanSeek`)